# Custom Fill formatter

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to have a chart that only fills a certain amount of points using mpandroid chart, I have looked at the wiki but I am directed to a 404 error when I try to look at the default fill formatter. The picture has all of the values filled. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.
 [image: line_chart_filled_data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it, the key here is to make multiple data sets with overlapping x indices and each dataset will have a point that doesn't overlap with the previous data set. Then specify which data set to setdrawfill(true/false).